# Custom validation that checks if email already exists in DB. HELP!

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm new to .net MVC but am making heads way. I'm trying to make a custom DataAnnotation validator that checks to see if an email address is already registered. I am using LINQ to SQL. My Model is below:

```
// Model
public class UsersRepository
{
    private DigitalentDataContext db = new DigitalentDataContext();
    BaseController baseController = new BaseController();

    //
    // Add talent user
    public void AddTalentUser(User user, TalentDetail talentDetail)
    {
        user.TalentDetails.Add(talentDetail);
        db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        string activationID = user.ActivationID.ToString();
        string activationEmail = user.Email;            
        baseController.SendConfEmail(activationID, activationEmail);
    }

    public IQueryable<User> GetAllUsers() 
    { 
        return db.Users; 
    }
}

//Validation

[MetadataType(typeof(UserValidation))]
public partial class User { }

[Bind(Exclude = "UserID")]
[ExistingEmailCheck("Email", ErrorMessage="Email address already registered")]
public class UserValidation 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name required"), StringLength(20, MinimumLength=3, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 3 and 20 characters")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    ...

}

public class ExistingEmailCheckAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public ExistingEmailCheckAttribute(string emailToCheck) {
        EmailToCheck = emailToCheck;
    }

    public string EmailToCheck { get; private set; }

    private UsersRepository _UserRep = new UsersRepository();        

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        int existingEmailCount = _UserRep.GetAllUsers().Where(g => g.Email == EmailToCheck).Count();
        return existingEmailCount == 0;
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Signup(User user, TalentDetail talentDetail)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {

            user.ActivationID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
            user.ActivationStatus = false;
            user.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;

            userRepository.AddTalentUser(user, talentDetail);                    
            return RedirectToAction("confirm", "login");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

All the other validations work but the ExistingEmailCheck doesn't. No error, nothing. Any Ideas?? Help is much appreciated.

Shahid

Comment: What does "Doesn't seem to work?" mean?  It either works or it doesn't, and if it doesn't, what does that mean, exception, doesn't validate, doesn't query, breakpoints don't hit?  What is your controller code?

Comment: Using an attribute to perform business logic is really bad form in my opinion. Verify that the email address is unique at time of insert and throw an exception.

Comment: @Ryan. I'm new to MVC im pretty sure the LINQtoSQL generated class does all the inserting. Do you mean putting a method in empty the partial class "public partial class User { }"?

Comment: I mean inside your `AddTalentUser` method you should check if an email address is already in use instead of having an attribute that checks for it.

Comment: That makes sense. How would i do that? Do you have a code example? Thanks

Comment: I would use `_UserRep.GetAllUsers().Any(g => g.Email == EmailToCheck)` and not do the insert if that returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you apply the filter to the specific Property instead of the Class?

Comment: Ryan to the rescue. See comments